# How to send latitude and longitude to webservice in android without internet?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, geolocation

I have an idea of making an app in that truck drivers are there with GPS,SO they will get latitude longitude without internet,there will be an admin panel which can track the truck driver's location and location history,So My question is that the truck drivers will only having a GPS enabled Android device (WITHOUT INTERNET),SO how can the admin will track their location? Please suggest me for it .

Comment: You want a real time tracking ?

Comment: i have no idea bout it but let me send what i want so that you can help me.here it it:Android application development 

1. Admin: Transport company will do the registration 
2. Registration will have detail of their Truck Drivers, trucks and company detail.
3. User(Truck driver) will install the application from play store
4. Admin can track the Truck driver’s location and history of the location.
5. While first time installation user must have to connect with Internet and send the Truck detail, after that user does not need to connect with Internet.

Comment: i think you won't be able to have a real time tracking (for admins) without internet.

If you don't care about real time, you could simply log all informations in a file/database and synchronized it when the drivers comes back

Comment: you can't able to do this without internet connection. Because you can call web services only if you have internet connection in mobile devices.

But if you want to develop this type of application. you can take that latitude and longitude, If internet connection is off you can store that lat long in to SQlite DB otherwise you can call web services to store that on Admin Panel

And whenever internet connection is on you can call web services using SQlite entries.

Hope this trick helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could try SMS messages, though, it might become rather expensive if the re-fresh rate for the location is high.

In simplest solution you would have a mobile device (you need to find one which incoming SMS you can fetch to the PC, might require some internet searching time) with normal number for receiving the SMS messages, or you could see whether you could get Operator service numbers (see whether using free-to-send number would be cheaper) and then get the data from the operator.

Comment: I have think about text message but its not the way

Comment: So, then you need to figure out other way on getting the data fro the device to the server, and I don't see too many alternatives, unless you would want to simple log the data into the device, and once they get back to your office, they would somehow connect the device to your server, which would then fetch the data from the device and store it in a database.